# Downloading a programmatically generated PDF on Mac OS X prompting security warnings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, pdf

I'm using iTextSharp to build PDF and serve it up as a downloading using C# and ASP.NET MVC 5. It works very well for the most part and renders well on Windows desktop environments.

Whilst testing on Mac OS X, I've noticed that when users download the PDF, users are presented with a security warning that pops up saying that the PDF cannot be opened as it is from an unidentified developer.

My understanding is that this is Gatekeeper(?) that has as issue with this file. Obviously I would not like to disable Gatekeeper or change any of the configuration on the client side. So I'm wondering if there is a way for me to configure this PDF so as to avoid this on OS X?

Comment: Are you using ssl with a self-signed certificate on your site?

Comment: As Gatekeeper has been tightened only with macOS Sierra, you would not see that effect if users were on OSX 10.11 and older. In addition, you might also check the MIME type settings for your PDF documents on the server, as it sounds strange that Gatekeeper reacts to a simple PDF.

Comment: A plain PDF file shouldn't trigger the Gatekeeper checks, since it's not considered executable. Is there some sort of additional metadata or something attached to it that Gatekeeper might be triggering on? Try running `ls -l@` on the downloaded file, and see if it lists anything other than "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate", "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms", and "com.apple.quarantine" attributes. If that doesn't show anything, I might need to look at an example file to get an idea what's going on.